# Method not found: 'DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalAliasCollection DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalAliasController.GetPortalAliases()

Tags: dotnetnuke

We working with psSiteSearch from Pure systms in DNN 7.03 we are getting the below error when we are click on site Search Admin edit settings.

Method not found: DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalAliasCollection DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalAliasController.GetPortalAliases()'

Answer (score 0):

Looking at information on this and looking at the changes in the DNN Core it would appear that this module has not been updated to work with the version of DNN that you are currently on.  http://www.puresystems.co.uk/services/dotnetnuke/dnn-modules/dnn-search-engine-pssitesearch/change-log